# Select entries with substring in a specific position of the word

Tags: sql, database, substring

I am trying to write an SQL query where my goal is to select all the entries that contains a substring in a specific position of a word (the entries are phrases with multiple words).

To make it clearer, suppose that I have these two entries (values inside a column, call it `phrase`):

1  -  "Jamming in New York"

2  -  "bosbessenjam 30g"

3  -  "30g bosbessenjam"

4  -  "Tranches de jambon fumé"

I want to select all the rows that contains a word that ends with "jam". So I want the second and third row.

I tried using `LIKE '%jam%'`, however it just check the overall string and not the single word. So `LIKE '%jam'` returns the third row, but not the second.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `select * from t where title like '%jam' or title like '%jam %'` ?

Comment: Yes! It worked as expected!